# Using regular expression failed to fetch expected date format

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to extract date from the text details using regular expression but the regular expression I am using it's return nothing.

The PHP code I am using to extract date from the strings:

```
<?php 
preg_match("/(\w\w\w)\,(\w\w\w) (\d\d)\,(\d\d\d\d) at (\d\d)\:(\d\d)   ([A|P]M)/", $input_line, $output_array);

?>
```

Input strings sample:

```
kardashian, kim this is dummy text area
mercury, freddie Tue, Aug 23, 2016 at 2:21 PM
22.11.2016 08:58 AM
last_name, first_name
bjorge, philip
```

Expected output:

```
Tue, Aug 23, 2016 at 2:21 PM
```

Please let me know why my regular expression is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Pay close attention to spaces (you're missing one after the first comma and have way too many before AM/PM).

Comment: `/(\w{3}), (\w{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4}) at (\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([AP]M)/` - Long story short: Your spaces didn't match and you expected hours to be 2 digits (it's only 1 in your example, `2:21`)

Answer (score 1):

You may fix this expression by adding space matching subpatterns, e.g. `\s` that matches any whitespace, or `\h` that matches horizontal whitespace only:

```
/\b(\p{L}{3}),\s(\p{L}{3})\s(\d\d),\s(\d{4})\sat\s(\d\d?):(\d\d)\s([AP]M)/
              ^^          ^^       ^^       ^^  ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH9bDf/2)

Wherever whitespace is optional, add `*` quantifier after it.

Also, to match `Tue`, `Aug`, you may just use the `\p{L}{3}` pattern (3 letters). Instead of `\d\d\d\d` you may write a shorter `\d{4}` equivalent. A `\b` word boundary in front is advisable, since you need to match the first 3-letter word as a whole word.

Also, `[A|P]` matches `A`, `|` or `P`, you need to remove the `|` from the character class.